# shell scripting "expect"ing various responses from ssh

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, expect

So I have a shell script which sshs into a machine, then using expect passes a password via expect and then runs a matlab script. The problem is I would like to do this for a whole range of machines on the network and if it's one that's I've not connected before asking me for a password it tells me that it can't authenticate the machine as asks me if I want to connect and awaits a yes\no response.

I want my shell script to be able to handle situations where it just asks for the password and where it also manages to deal with the yes\no. I don't know how to go about doing this with "expect" as when it doesn't receive what it expects it just hangs.

Also for some reason my additional code to handle the yes no response doesn't work when testing it with machines I know I haven't logged in with. This is format with which they reply.

"The authenticity of host 'seven (128.40.41.89)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is d6:9d:d0:61:5f:bb:36:9a:74:2c:f6:b9:a7:79:03:98.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?"

And this is my code which for some reason doesn't work with my addition, but works fine with just the "assword:" bit which I found on stack exchange. I can see the terminal and it asks the yes\no question, but then my script doesn't respond. I'm guessing I'm somehow using the expect wrong, but I have no idea how.

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh seven
expect "(yes\no)? "
send "yes\r"
expect "assword:"
send "my password goes here\r"

matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nosplash -nodesktop -r \
"try, run('\path\matlab_script.m'), catch me, fprintf('%s / %s \n',me.identifier,me.message), end, exit"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible workaround is running ssh with StrictHostKeyChecking set to no:

```
ssh seven -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

This will autimatically add unknown host keys to the list of known hosts.

Comment: @generic, there is an expect solution to this (search for "yes/no exp_continue") but this is a better way to do it.

Comment: Spasibo Oleg, ochen blagodaren!

And thank you Glenn, could be useful for future problems.